# I would like to know how to combine If, AND and OR in a complex statement in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem I would like some help with. I am generating random numbers to convert to a password using chr($v). I am using an if statement to make sure I only use printable characters. I have got this successfully working in C++ for Arduino and Pascal using Lazarus for Windows & Linux. I am now trying to write a Web based version and cannot get the code below to work, in either form in PHP 7.3. The first one is the one that works in C++ and Pascal, although in Pascal I have to use the words AND and OR!
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Many thanks.

```
if (($v > 47) && ($v < 58)) || (($v > 64) && ($v <91)) || (($v > 96) && ($v < 123))
```

```
if ($v > 47 && $v < 58) || ($v > 64 && $v <91) || ($v > 96 && $v < 123)
```

Comment: When you say that you "_cannot get the code below to work_", what exactly about it isn't working?

Comment: You can just do a regex match of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: Martin, I mean that when the page loads, even with error reporting enabled, I just get "This page isn't working" in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, the **if** statement must have a pair of round brackets enclosing all the conditions

So

```
if (condition a) || (condition b)
{}
```

will have **syntax error**, and you need to have

```
if ((condition a) || (condition b))
{}
```

So for your case, please change:

```
if ($v > 47 && $v < 58) || ($v > 64 && $v <91) || ($v > 96 && $v < 123)
```

to

```
if (($v > 47 && $v < 58) || ($v > 64 && $v <91) || ($v > 96 && $v < 123))
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to upvote this answer, but many thanks Ken Lee, it worked a treat!! I wasn't aware of the finer points of difference in PHP. This is the first time I have tried a multi conditional IF statement in PHP!!